# Show Foriegn key data (names etc) instead of just the forign key in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a medical application for a Drs Practice as part of an assignment.

I have a table which is displaying the information with to the visits table which is linked in the image here.
[image: Mysql Info]

Currently the table is displaying the Id values of the foriegn keys like this

[image: Appointment Table]

How do i display the text value for example rather than patient name being 9, i would like to display the actual name and so on for the rest of the table.

so it will display as

```
patient name | doctor | condition | medication prescribed | Date
Andrew Terry | Dr Iqbal | Depression | Fluoxetine | 20th April 2018
```

I am also when i have worked this out, wanting to add a search where i can search for patients with a certain condition within a certain time period.

The current code is as follows

```
    <?php // Include config file
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/config.php");
?>
<?php // Include header File
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/header.php");
?>
<?php
if (!$db) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM visit JOIN doctor
            ON visit.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id 
            JOIN patient
            ON visit.patient_id = patient.patient_id
            WHERE patient.patient_id BETWEEN 1 AND 9
            ORDER BY date DESC";


$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if (!$query) {
  die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
  }
?>

<body>
<?php // Navigation File
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/nav.php");?>
<div class="container"><br><br>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/logo.html"); ?>

  <h2>APPOINTMENTS</h2>

  <p>Most Recent Appointments:</p>            
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>Doctor</th>
        <th>Condition</th>
        <th>Medication Prescribed</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['patient_id'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['doctor_id'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['con_id'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['drugs_id'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['date'].'</td> 
                    <td><a href="deleteapp.php?id='.($row['visit_id']).'" class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>';    
            $no++;
        }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="newapp.php" class="btn btn-success pull-left">New Appointment</a>
  <a href="../" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Admin Area</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have amended code following @kamal assistance earlier.. but now i am getting undefined notice errors.

Code is as follows

```
<?php // Include config file
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/config.php");
?>
<?php // Include header File
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/header.php");
?>
<?php
if (!$db) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql  = "$sql  = "SELECT patient.fName AS pfname, patient.sName AS psname, doctor.sName AS doc, conditions.con_name AS con, drugs.medication AS meds, visit.visitdate FROM visit 
            JOIN doctor ON visit.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id
            JOIN patient ON visit.patient_id = patient.patient_id
            LEFT JOIN conditions ON visit.con_id = conditions.con_id
            LEFT JOIN drugs ON visit.drugs_id = drugs.med_id
            WHERE patient.patient_id BETWEEN 1 AND 100
            ORDER BY date DESC";


$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if (!$query) {
  die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
  }
?>

<body>
<?php // Navigation File
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/nav.php");?>
<div class="container"><br><br>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/logo.html"); ?>

  <h2>APPOINTMENTS</h2>

  <p>Most Recent Appointments:</p>            
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>Doctor</th>
        <th>Condition</th>
        <th>Medication Prescribed</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['pfName'].'</td> 
                    <td>'."Dr ".$row['doc'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['con'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['meds'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['date'].'</td> 
                    <td><a href="deleteapp.php?id='.($row['visit_id']).'" class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>';    
            $no++;
        }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="newapp.php" class="btn btn-success pull-left">New Appointment</a>
  <a href="../" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Admin Area</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am now getting the following. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXp0z.jpg)

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: You need to join the table with the tables that have all the names.

Comment: This is an assignment for a class? Don't they teach you the basics before giving assignments?

Comment: not in my uni no.. they are pretty terrible, i have pretty much had to teach myself everything.

Comment: I hae added code @Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume few of the tables in the following answer.

Here how your query should look like as @Barmar mentioned in comment:

```
SELECT fName,date,visit_id,patient.patient_name, doctor.name AS doctor_name, condition.name AS condition_name, drugs.name AS drugs_name FROM visit JOIN doctor
        ON visit.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id 
        JOIN patient
        ON visit.patient_id = patient.patient_id
        LEFT JOIN condition ON visit.con_id = condition.id
        LEFT JOIN drugs ON visit.drugs_id = drugs.id
        WHERE patient.patient_id BETWEEN 1 AND 9
        ORDER BY date DESC
```

Then within your PHP code, you should change the column names in while loop as below:

```
echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['patient_name'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['doctor_name'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['condition_name'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['drugs_name'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['date'].'</td> 
                <td><a href="deleteapp.php?id='.($row['visit_id']).'" class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>';
```

I hope this will help you to move forward.

Comment: I am getting a "SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition ON visit.con_id = con_name LEFT JOIN drugs ON visit.drugs_id = medica' at line 5" 
Error?

Comment: condition is system variable so you should change your table name to something else rather than condition.

Comment: the table is called conditions and the column is called con_name buddy.

Comment: where can i add updated code on stackoverflow? I have amended my code but i keep getting unidentified indexs and also date is not showing.

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED THE ORIGINAL POST.

Comment: date is also system variable, you should also change it, you should post what kind of undefined index you are getting..

Comment: i have underneath the code at the bottom of the post. im only able to post img links as i do not have a high enough score to display them.

Comment: You should change your SQL query and put missing columns such as SELECT fName,date,visit_id,patient.patient_name, doctor.name AS doctor_name, condition.name AS condition_name, drugs.name AS drugs_name FROM visit